# What is a word for creating artificial desire, such as in a consumer marketplace?

Tags: synonyms

The context is describing how corporate marketers aim to create needs in the minds of consumers which they go on to satisfy with their products.

Example: "The global multinational corporation _____ (stimulates|inflames|excites) our individual appetites..."

Note: 'cater to' or 'appeal to' do not fit here, because those connote legitimate pre-existing needs. I'm looking for a word that connotes a fabricated need.

Comment: Pre-existing or not, *appeal* does work here...anyway, demand marketing to create artificial needs. I'd stay away from appetite here...

Comment: Stimulates seems to fit.

Comment: Advertising almost **invents** that desire.

Comment: I believe the maxim is "sex sells", so such ads aren't creating a need but fanning the fire and transfering the heat to their product.  But some ads do plant an idea in the minds of the viewers. How can I go on living unless I buy that product???

Comment: [*fanning the fire,fanning the **flames***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fanning+the+fire%2Cfanning+the+flames&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: The big multinational [*create **and** satisfy demand.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22create+and+satisfy+demand%22) That's a *lot* of written instances,

Comment: They *exploit* our desires.

Comment: *Manufacture our desires* has an industrial quality which is relevant. There are a lot of other metaphors and images: kindle, nourish, create, seed, conjure, instill...

Comment: 'Create a market [for]' is perhaps the most common expression. But you need to tick the 'single word request' box to remain true to your title question.

Comment: One aspect is to create the idea of inadequacy, which can be restored by buying the product.

Comment: All helpful, thank you. Also someone suggested "whet" (as pertaining to appetites).

Comment: Are seeking a term for creating desires **from scratch** or for **intensifying** the desires that already exist in some weaker form?

Comment: whet is best, yes. If you must use the word appetite...

Comment: @jsw29 From scratch

Comment: @nich, OK, but then you should make that explicit within the question, as it rules out several of the terms that have been proposed.

Comment: I don't think *whet* works very well; it's a sharpening of something incipient, something already there. Try: *The global multinational corporation manufactures appetites for its products...*

Comment: @TinfoilHat Manufactures would work if it wasn't preceded by "multinational corporation" which conjures a different meaning. But in other contexts, yes.

Comment: @Lambie There are many great suggestions but 'whet' is the best in this circumstance (and what I went with). I will accept this as an answer.

Comment: @nich It isn't posted, shall I post it? :)

Comment: The play on words makes it all the more pointed: *The global multinational corporation manufactures appetites for its products.*

Comment: @Lambie Yes please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merriam Webster:

2
: to make keen or more acute : EXCITE, STIMULATE
whet the appetite
whetted her curiosity

Sample sentence:
**"The global multinational corporation **whetted** our individual appetites..."** [for whatever]

Comment: As Tinfoil Hat already pointed out in a comment below the question, *whet* doesn't work well, because it stands for 'a sharpening of something incipient, something already there', while the OP seeks a term for creating desires from scratch rather than a term for intensifying the desires that already exist in some weaker form. (Unfortunately, the OP made that clear only in a comment, and did not incorporate it into the question itself.)

Comment: This is what I ultimately went with, best fitting the context of "appetites" though many other suggestions here were valid (conjure, concoct, invent, manufacture...). Although I did intend "from scratch" it's possible to create an appetite that otherwise wouldn't exist. Such as when you see a billboard for cheeseburgers driving down the road at 2pm and you suddenly become hungry. Even though you would have eventually eaten a few hours later, its still an implanted desire that wouldn't have existed under different circumstances (i.e., walking in a forest).

Comment: @jsw29 Yes but the appetite is there, it is just increased.  Desire or wish or wanting something is not associated with the idea of from scratch. And you can't hype an appetite. So...

Answer (score 2):

Hyping [[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/hyping)]:

> **hype**
>
> - [verb] (used with object); hyped, hyping.
>
>   to create interest in by flamboyant or dramatic methods
>
>   to intensify (advertising, promotion, or publicity) by ingenious or questionable claims, methods, etc. (usually followed by up).
> - [noun]
>   an ingenious or questionable claim, method, etc., used in advertising, promotion, or publicity to intensify the effect.

Answer (score 1):

Advertising **conjures up** a desire that did not previously exist. In the OED's definition, it "bring[s] into existence as by magic."

> **conjure** (v.)
>
> Imagine, contrive
>
> —Often used with up
>
> *We conjure up our own metaphors for our own needs …*
> —R. J. Kaufmann
>
> *Conjured up a clever plan to raise the money*
> [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conjure)

> **conjure something up** (phrasal verb)
>
> To make a picture or idea appear in someone's mind:
>
> *The glittering ceremony conjured up images of Russia's imperial past.*
> *For some people, the word "England" may still conjure up images of pretty gardens and tea parties.*
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/conjure-up?q=conjure%20something%20up)

> **to conjure up**: to raise or bring into existence as by magic, occult influence, the art or tricks of the conjuror; to cause to
> appear to the fancy.
>
> **1600** *A manly enterprise, To coniure teares vp, in a poore maides eyes.*
> W. Shakespeare, *Midsummer Night's Dream* iii. ii. 159
> [OED
> online]

---

> The term 'neuromarketing' was first used in 2002, although one might
> say that the classical Marlboro arid Midwest images were early
> examples of neuromarketing; the Marlboro brand was so strong that
> simply seeing a a billboard image of a cowboy on horseback amongst the
> desert mesas might **conjure up a desire** to buy that particular
> brand of cigarettes.
> [Hillary J. Shaw and Julia Shaw; Corporate Social
> Responsibility, Social Justice and the Global Food Supply Chain](https://books.google.com/books?id=L_-GDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT170&dq=corporations%20conjure%20up%20desire&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjH34GKo9GEAxVOFmIAHR6jCyUQ6AF6BAgMEAI#v=onepage&q=corporations%20conjure%20up%20desire&f=false)
> (2019)

> The benefit that desire brought advertisers is that, unlike need, it
> is potentially open-ended. As soon as you have something you desire,
> the desire ends—thus, for advertisers the trick is to constantly
> **conjure up new desires**. Advertisers therefore realizes that products had to be constantly evolved though the cyclical creation of
> this year's model, this year's design, this year's colours or this
> year's new sports star.
> [Peter Craig; *Sport Sociology*](https://books.google.com/books?id=irAaDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT298&dq=advertising%20conjures%20up%20desire&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUhquNqNGEAxUlFFkFHV8iDJ8Q6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q=advertising%20conjures%20up%20desire&f=false) (2016)

> Yes, of course we're trying to sell the steak but what is often most
> effective in promoting this or any other product is our ability to
> **conjure up a mood or a desire** that is linked to smell and taste and sound and sensation—and which makes this steak particularly
> memorable and desirable to our audience.
> [Robert Bowdery; *Basic Advertising 01: Copywriting*](https://books.google.com/books?id=QWlC0pnk1IcC&pg=PA19&dq=advertising%20conjures%20up%20desire&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUhquNqNGEAxUlFFkFHV8iDJ8Q6AF6BAgFEAI#v=onepage&q=advertising%20conjures%20up%20desire&f=false) (2008)

> Shop 'show windows' constitute part of a range of techniques, events,
> and media that were developed to cultivate a commercial aesthetic of
> desire. Along with 'electrical signs, fashion shows, advertisements
> and billboards' they were designed to **conjure up a consumer
> vision** of 'the good life and of paradise', the primary objective
> being to entice consumers into shops and promote the sale of goods in
> substantial volume (Leach, 1993:9).
> [Barry Smart; *Consumer
> Society*](https://books.google.com/books?id=b8CNmCe0AisC&pg=PA104&dq=advertising%20conjures%20up%20desire&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiOg--1qtGEAxVcGFkFHU1uCZE4ChDoAXoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=advertising%20conjures%20up%20desire&f=false) (2010)

Answer (score 0):

There is the choice of a very usual term in this context; that is the verb "*to create*". An examination of this [page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22create%20a%20need%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) will show that in commercial contexts it is often used with the word "need" (create a need). In order to use it in this sentence it would have to be slightly modified.

- The global multinational corporation creates new appetites  ...

Comment: The word *creating* already appears in the question, so the OP is already familiar with it. What this answer really amounts to is a challenge to the OP to explain why the OP needs a different word.

Comment: whets our appetite. One creates demand for x, I don't much like creat3es new appetites. Generally, though singular appetite.

Comment: @Lambie In the literal sense (physical desire for food), I agree, "create an appetite" will seem odd (very specific context needed); in the figurative sense "appetite" is only countable, and I don't see why not use a plural; In this sense of "strong desire" I do not agree with you; it seems in fact that this phrase is a collocation of the language (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=create+new+appetites&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3). "Whet" is a relevant term as applied to the literal concept and it can be applied figuratively, but it means "increase".